# How to get types of an attribute in an interface c#

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

Working with an add-in for Enterprise Architect (EA) I need to get all the different types a Test can have in EA.

By this I mean that the Test class in the EA namespace inherits from an IDualTest interface which has the get/set method for the string attribute named "Type". As a standard EA has 3 different types (Standard, Regression, Load) but it is possible to add your own types. I need to get all these types.

I believe that this is possible with reflection but that is not my strongest site so I could really use some help here.
Please comment if more information is needed.

EDIT:

I've got the following code:

```
List<string> typeList = new List<string>();

            foreach (string type in Test.Types)
            {
                typeList.Add(type);
            }
```

The above code is not compileable but I hope it illustrates my needs.

```
 foreach (Test t in elm.Tests)
        {
            string type = t.Type; //It is this type that can be the standards from EA and your own added types
        }
```

//    -  Output

//Standard

//Regression

//Load

//CustomType1

//CustomType2

Comment: consider trying something and see where you stuck... At this point there is a good chance this question should be duplicate of one of many "how to get types/attributes/fields via reflection"...

Comment: Well, I will try to update with some code. But I don't really know where to start and that's my problem. Thx to the guy that downvoted without leaving a comment gotta love those guys!

Comment: On "downvote without comment" - check out http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267498/getting-downvoted-yet-no-comment-as-to-why (and links from that META discussion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There no use for reflection here.
These values are stored in the EA database.
The "proper" way of querying the API is to use Repository.GetReferencType() like this:

```
EA.Reference testTypes = Repository.GetReferenceList("Test");
for (short i = 0; i < testTypes.Count; i++)
{
    string testType = testTypes.GetAt(i);
}
```

If you need more then only the name you can query the database directly: 
`Repository.SQLQuery("select * from t_testtypes")`

Comment: Is it possible to add a testType by code? I've tried Repository.SQLQuery("INSERT INTO t_testtypes VALUES (Default)"); but it didn't work. Also it doesn't look like the EA.Reference has a AddNew().

Comment: @n.Stenvang Yes you can, but then you have to use ´Repository.Execute("Insert into t_...")´

Comment: Just to add the syntax: Repository.Execute("INSERT INTO t_testtypes (TestType, Description, NumericWeight, Notes) VALUES ('Default', 'Default value','1,000000','Some description')"); 

And then I must add that the Repository.Execute() is an undocumented feature.